# web.config <system.webServer> error

Tags: web-config, monitoring, self-healing

VS 2015, .Net Framework 4.5.1, local IISExpress and Azure Web App

Attempting to follow self healing config settings from: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/auto-healing-windows-azure-web-sites/

Error: The element 'system.webServer' has invalid child element 'monitoring'

The app compiles but fails at runtime both when run locally in VS2015 and when deployed to azure web app.

Comment: also according to this reference, there is no <monitoring> child:; https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver

Comment: Did anyone ever figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

I got around this issue by transforming the Web.Release.config file, for instance:

```
<system.webServer>
<monitoring xdt:Transform="Insert">
    <triggers>
        <statusCode>
            <add statusCode="500" count="10" timeInterval="00:00:30" />
        </statusCode>
    </triggers>
</monitoring>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried to include this Auto-Healing feature in my web app and I also got an internal server error when including this in my web.config and run locally.

```
  <system.webServer>
    ...
    <monitoring>
      <triggers>
        <slowRequests timeTaken="00:00:30" count="5" timeInterval="00:10:00" />
      </triggers>
      <actions value="Recycle" />
    </monitoring>
  </system.webServer>
```

However in my azure publication I have modified the web.config (using kudu) and restarted my web app with no errors.

Mine is an Stardard app service plan

For now I have no verified if this trigger has some effect

hope this helps !